# How To Update EnvironmentObject From Child View When ViewModel Async Func Completes

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

In my SwiftUI app I have an entry point as follows

```
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppContainerView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct AppContainerView: View {
    @StateObject var appState = AppState()
    var body: some View {
        if appState.isLoggedIn && appState.hasSeenOnboarding {
            TabContainerView()
        } else {
            LandingView().environmentObject(appState)
        }
    }
}
```

I can update the `isLoggedIn` like so...

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []
    private let userService: UserServiceProtocol
    init(userService: UserServiceProtocol = UserService()) {
        self.userService = userService
        subscribeForAuthChanges()
    }
    
    func subscribeForAuthChanges() {
        userService.authChangeSubject.sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] auth, user in
            print(auth)
            if user != nil {
                self?.isLoggedIn = true
            }
        }).store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    @Published var isLoggedIn = false
    @Published var hasSeenOnboarding = false
}
```

But when it comes to `hasSeenOnboarding` this needs to be set to true after some network call has completed in a viewModel in one of `LandingView` child views. I can do something like this...

```
struct ChildView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
  @StateObject var viewModel = ChildViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      //...
    }.onReceive($viewModel.networkCallCompleted) { completed in
       self.appState.hasSeenOnboarding = completed
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't feel right...is there a better option here to change the appState from a childView/viewModel when using MVVM? Or perhaps a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible alternative is to pass the `AppState` to the `ChildViewModel` and perform `AppState` updates directly in the view model.

```
struct ParentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

  var body: some View {
    ChildView(viewModel: ChildViewModel(appState: appState))
  }
}
```

```
struct ChildView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
  @StateObject var viewModel: ChildViewModel

  var body: some View {
    ...
  }
}
```

---

**Note**

You may want to take a look at **dependency injection** to make it cleaner. Here is a possible example: [Simple Dependency Injection using @propertyWrapper](https://fmo91.github.io/0002-dependency-injection-using-property-wrappers/).

Comment: Thanks this works - although when I change the @Published hasSeenOnboarding property to @AppStorage(AppState.hasSeenOnboardingKey) var hasSeenOnboarding: Bool = false it doesn't reload the view for some reason

Comment: @jeh `@AppStorage` should be used in View only (just like `@State`).